# execute function after AJAX complete object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add data to a dynamic modal. The modal should only come into view once the data has been added to the model. I have tried to achieve this using the line `$.when(Ss.pieceInfo(piece)).then(Ss.showInfo());` but it seems both functions are executing at the same time. What

```
var Ss = {
    $modal: $('#piece-modal'),
    $title: $('.piece-title'),
    $artist: $('.piece-artist'),
    $info: $('.piece-info'),


    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $('.piece').on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var piece = $(this).data('slug');

        //This doesn't seem to have any effect
            $.when(Ss.pieceInfo(piece)).then(Ss.showInfo());
        });
    },

    pieceInfo: function(piece) {
        console.log(piece);
        $.getJSON(Kirby.baseUrl + '/api/v1/work/' + piece, function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
                Ss.$title.html(val.title);
                Ss.$artist.html(val.artist); 
                Ss.$info.html(val.text);
            })
        });
    },

    showInfo: function() {
        var height = $('.primary-info').height();
        console.log(height)
        Ss.$modal.addClass('modal-active')
        Ss.$modal.css('transform','translate3D(0, calc(100% - '+ height +'px), 0)');
    },
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    Ss.init();
});
```

Comment: Try adding a slight timeout to your method that updates your modal.

This way you can see if they are actually executing at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are not returning the promise in the `Ss.pieceInfo()` method, causing it to be resolved instantly. [As per the documentation for `$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

> If a single argument is passed to `jQuery.when()` and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

To do that, you will have to change that method only very slightly: return the `$.getJSON` promise.

```
pieceInfo: function(piece) {
    return $.getJSON(Kirby.baseUrl + '/api/v1/work/' + piece, function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
            Ss.$title.html(val.title);
            Ss.$artist.html(val.artist); 
            Ss.$info.html(val.text);
        })
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I've realised I want to execute `Ss.showInfo()` after the data has been painted to the screen.